# Pop up on ajax success

Tags: javascript, ajax, popup

I have this modal pop up when a link is clicked. It has a text area and 2 buttons: Send and cancel

```
   <a href="#message" style="text-decoration:none" class="common2 simple3" >Message</a>
        <div id="message" class="modalDialog">
                <div>
                    <!---<a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>--->
                    <h3>Create A Message</h3>


                    <textarea  id = 'msgContent' cols="48" rows="10" ></textarea>
                    <br>
                    <div id="create_btn">
                        <a href="#" id = 'send' class="common simple2" style='margin-left:50px;text-decoration: none;'>Send</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="cancel_btn">
                        <a href="#close" class="common simple2" style='margin-left:40px;text-decoration: none;'>cancel</a>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div id="success" class="modalDialog">
                <div>
                    <h3>Message sent</h3>
                    <div id="cancel_btn">
                        <a href="#close" class="common simple2" style='margin-left:40px;text-decoration: none;'>OK</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

and i have this code in ajax success when the send button is clicked

```
  success: function(result)
                        {                                           

                            if (result == true)
                            $( "#success" ).dialog( "" );

                        }
```

I am working on showing another pop up when the ajax is successful. But I have no idea how to call

```
  <div id="success" class="modalDialog">
```

Comment: Are you getting any error check the console log, are you using any plugin for modal dialog?

Comment: no, i am not using any plug in. The error is .dialog(), it says there is no method like that.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is check if ajax call is success by keeping an alert in it.

```
success: function(result){                                           
      if (result == true)
        alert('working');
      else 
        alert('not working');
```

}

if your alert i 'working' then check if you are including jqueryui https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

dialog() is a jquery ui function not a javascript predefine function.

Comment: i was using the alert() earlier but it is boring that i want something more eye- catching so i created a div in the html and i plan to call it if the ajax is successful.